# jQuery, not working with span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I get jQuery to work with a span id tag?

jQuery is not seeing my id correctly. When I use the h6 tags without the span, it works fine. I'm open to using a div or some other work around.
Thanks,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "><html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('#PlusMinus').click(function() {
    if($(this).val() == "+") {
        $(this).val("-");
    }else {
        $(this).val("+");
    }
    $("body h6").toggle();
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
  <input type='button' value='+' id='PlusMinus'/>
  <!--WITH SPAN THE CODE BREAKS-->
      <span id="h6">Larger</span>
      <span id="h6" style="display: none">Smaller</span>
</body>
</html>
```

WITHOUT SPAN
 h6 Larger /h6
 
 h6 style="display: none">Smaller /h6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elements should have unique ID's.  Also, your selector is wrong (you would use a # in front if selecting an ID).  Try using a class since you want to affect more than one item:

```
<span class="h6">Larger</span>

$('.h6').toggle();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple span elements with the same id. An id must be unique. Use a class instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have two elements with the same id on the page. You are expected to have unique ids per element.

Try this which should work:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('#PlusMinus').click(function() {
    if($(this).val() == "+") {
        $(this).val("-");
    }else {
        $(this).val("+");
    }
    $("body .h6").toggle();
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
  <input type='button' value='+' id='PlusMinus'/>
  <!--WITH SPAN THE CODE BREAKS-->
      <span class="h6">Larger</span>
      <span class="h6" style="display: none">Smaller</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two elements (your spans) with "h6" as the ID, change one of them... ID's should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was wrong ID. What helped me out:

```
$('#span.id').html('bla bla');
```

changed to

```
$('#span-id').html('bla bla');
```